# How to load data in specified database by Spring Data Mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have configured Spring Mongodb project to load data in database named "warehouse". Here is how my config class looks like

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {


   @Override
   protected String getDatabaseName() {
      return "warehouse";
   }

   public @Bean Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
      return new Mongo("localhost");
   }

   public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
      return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), getDatabaseName());
   }
}
```

But Spring is always using the default database "test" to store and retrieve the collections. I have tried different approaches to point it to "warehouse" db. But it doesnt seem to work. What am doing wrong? Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a standard mongo install (e.g., the database is at a default such as /data/db or C:\data\db), your configuration class looks correct. How are you using it? Can you try:

```
SpringMongoConfig config = new SpringMongoConfig();
MongoTemplate template = config.mongoTemplate();
template.createCollection("someCollection");
```

From a shell, if you then log into `mongo` and enter `show dbs`, do you not see a warehouse"?

Comment: I am using it like this,   

`@Autowired  
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;  
mongoTemplate.findAll(query, XYZ.class);`

Comment: Can you update the question and post the application code that's trying to use the mongoTemplate bean?